# Stream over a list to feed other lists in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `List<EmployeeDetails>` which contains total list of employees among the organization.

```
EmployeeDetails.java

private String name;
private String designation;
//other property
```

I want loop over above `list` and feed the element into model class which contains many types of lists

```
Emoloyee.java

List<Manager> manager;
List<Intern> intern;
List<TeamLead> teamLead;
List<Support> support;


Manager.java

private String name;
private String designation;
//other property
```

How can I feed `Employee.java` by only single loop over `List<EmployeeDetails>`?

I know I can use `for` loop against list and create each type of list based on designation and feed to model but I am looking for a better approach where I don't want to create many list.

Is there any better approach where I can feed to model on-the-fly in single loop.

Comment: 1. Inheriting `Manager`, `Intern`, `Support` and `TeamLead` from an `Employee` would be a better design. 2. Using an `enum Designation` would further simplify it. 3. You ca then use `groupingBy` and choose to get all those lists from the flattened employee details list.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.  You may need to modify this to fit your exact requirement.

```
List<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Intern> interns = new ArrayList<>();
List<TeamLead> teamLeads = new ArrayList<>();
List<Support> support    = new ArrayList<>();

forEach(EmployeeDetails ed : employDetailList) {
    switch(ed.getDesignation()) {
        // get the proper info from `ed` to create the position objects.
        case "Manager": managers.add(new Manager(....);
        break;
        case "Intern": interns.add(new Intern(....));
        break;
        case "TeamLead": teamLeads.add(new TeamLead(....));
        break;
        case "Support": support.add(new Support(....));
        break;
    }
}
```

However, this is rather cumbersome.  You may want to rethink your design. For example, have the different position classes be a subclass of Employee.

Comment: How can I map it to `List<Manager>` in `Employee.java`. This Map will give me `List<EmployeeDetails>` that I need to convert to specific List of object

Comment: So you want to go from the details list to four lists of each object type?

Comment: yes.. I want to single loop over details list and create list of each object type.

Comment: Choosing to [implement the `Designation` as enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877373/stream-over-a-list-to-feed-other-lists-in-java#comment116477500_65877373) would simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java8 you can convert **EmployeeDetails** list to designation wise map as:

```
Map<String, List<EmployeeDetails>> designationListMap = employees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeDetails ::getDesignation));
```

and after you can retrieve a list of EmployeeDetails for specific designation:

```
designationListMap.get("Manager");
```